# How to create Spring Cache KeyGenerator that allows no caching for specified key

Tags: spring, spring-cache

I just want to disable cache for users that are admins. So I write a method to generate keys as below that returns null for admins. But I get

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null key returned for cache
>   operation 
>   exeption.

Is there any way achieve that?

```
//a method that generates a menu for each user
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "topmenu", keyGenerator = "uiComponentKey")
@Override
public String renderResponse() {...}   


//method used by a key generator to generate cache keys.
@Override
public Object getCacheKey() {
    if (user.isAdmin()) {
        return null;
    }
    return user.getUser().getLogin() + "@" + "topmenu";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can achive that using [conditional caching feature](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-condition). Smth like this:

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "topmenu", condition="#user.isAdmin()")
@Override
public String renderResponse(User user) {...}
```

Note, that you're going to have to pass user object to this method in this case.